# Access images from storage folder

Tags: php, laravel

I upload images to a storage folder storage/app/public but I also add additional folders to store them in a more useful way for me

C:\xampp\htdocs\rps\storage\app\public\images\user-profile

I managed to save them without a problem but now I don't know how to access them in my .blade.php file I tried:

```
src="storage/images/user-profile/standard/default.png"
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\rps\storage\app\public\images\user-profile\standard\default.png

or

```
src="storage/images/user-profile/standard/{{$person->avatar}}"
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\rps\storage\app\public\images\user-profile\standard\1558700163.jpg

but it didn't work for me, anyone can help. I guess my path is wrong

Do I also need to add public/storage folders?

Comment: If you are using the storage helpers with the public storage disk you can get [file urls](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-urls)

Answer (score 1):

Configure a new disk in `config/filesystems.php` like so:

```
'images' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('images'),
],
```

Then to get the URL:

```
$url = Storage::disk('images')->url('file.jpg');
```

And to get the file content:

```
$contents = Storage::disk('images')->get('file.jpg');
```

You can also use the `storage_path()` helper. So in your views this should work:

```
src="{{storage_path('images/user-profile/standard/default.png')}}"
```

Read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem) for further info.

Comment: also {{asset('images/user-profile/standard').'/'.$person->avatar}}

Comment: Still picture doesn't show up on the website https://i.imgur.com/SCGYD4G.png
src shows perfectly the path to the picture http://rps.me/images/user-profile/standard/1558704557.jpg I think but still picture doesn't show up (my local path C:\xampp\htdocs\rps\storage\app\public\images\user-profile\standard\1558704557.jpg)
404 not found error

Comment: @S0ul3r The `storage_path()` helper should work as it returns the absolute path. The URL is not gonna work unless you add a symlink to `/public` with `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: @Archie Unfortunately I already added symlink to /public. Both storage_path() and IRL doesnt work for me. But if I use src to public path like this one everything shows up as intended: 

`C:\xampp\htdocs\rps\public\files\assets\images\user-profile\standard`

`src="/files/assets/images/user-profile/standard/{{$person->avatar}}"`

Comment: @S0ul3r What does `storage_path()` actually return?

Comment: @Archie `src="{{storage_path('app\public\images\user-profile\standard\default.png')}}"` 
returns
`C:\xampp\htdocs\rps\storage\app\public\images\user-profile\standard\default.png`
which is exact path to the default image, when I paste the path to explorer is gives me an image that I want

When I load the page console returns: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/rps/storage/app/public/images/user-profile/standard/default.png`

Comment: @S0ul3r It's a Windows/xampp permissions thing. Can't help you with that, unfortunately.